# It is feasible to complete decouple a graphics engine from game logic?

Tags: architecture

Is it possible, or even feasible, to have graphics engine completely decoupled from game logic?

Why I ask is because I want to start working on a game (I'm a complete beginner in game development, but I have 8+ years of programming under my belt), but there are more than a couple graphics engines out there to pick from. Also I do not anticipate my development speed will be very fast, so I would like to be able to swap out an old graphics engine for a new one if the old one becomes too out of date.

I want to work with OpenGL for possible cross platform compatibility, so that should at least reduce issues that may arise from supporting multiple graphics APIs.

Comment: For 2D games, it should be easy to change an engine, because the most important thing you need from your engine is drawing textures on the screen. Everything else is just performance issues. One thing to consider if you are planning on using shaders and switch from an opengl based engine to a directX one, you will probably have to change a couple of things in your code.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the question "Is it possible, or even feasible, to have graphics engine completely decoupled from game logic?" is "yes".

I would say it is even "advisable".

But in general, you'll find a lot of your game ends up tied to the engine you choose for other reasons, like input handling or use of their facebook integration or other cross-platform services.

Comment: Going further, I've yet to find any two engines where a material effect or post-process can be dropped-in from one to another without substantial adjustments. So even if the basics of loading, transforming & displaying models/sprites is consistent, as soon as you want to do anything the least bit fancy you'll usually end up with at least some code/data that needs to be specifically tuned for your current engine's graphics pipeline.

Comment: @DMGregory are you talking about game engines or graphics engines?

Comment: How about if I create, say, a generic interface(s) and then I implement adapters for each game engine... would that be feasible? Or just overhead, as I will likely only need to swap out graphics engines a few times in the game's lifetime?

Comment: @Populus I think you're overthinking it. The engines available today are extremely capable. If you pick one you like right now, you're unlikely to regret that choice in a 2-3 year horizon (and in games, trying to plan any further ahead than that is basically astrology). You're only likely to outgrow such an engine if you're doing something really bleeding-edge in terms of experimental graphics tech, in which case you'd probably end up writing your own graphics pipeline down to the metal anyway.